supportFragmentManager not working as intended
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = UiInterfaceBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
    taskViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[TaskViewModel::class.java]
    binding.newTaskButton.setOnClickListener {
        TaskSheet(null).show(supportFragmentManager(), "newTaskTag")
    }
    setRecyclerView()
}

I've tried to link support fragment manager and I've added all imports and tried different ways it just does seem like it wants to link to it
In my taskSheet there isn't a  show function thats different instead its overrides of it but I wont do an override of taskManager for some reason

What exactly isn't working and what do you want to do?
